# cordova app issues with page caching options

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, caching

I have run into a problem with cordova page caching:

```
  .state('tab.clubs', {
    cache: true,
    url: '/clubs',
    params: tabParams,
    views: {
      'tab-clubs': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-clubs.html',
        controller: 'ClubCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('tab.club-detail', {
    cache: false,
    url: '/clubs/:ceID',
    params: tabParams,
    views: {
      'tab-clubs': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/detail-clubs.html',
        controller: 'ClubDetailCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

Specifically its `tab.club-detail` child page.  On the specific page there are two buttons.  Depending on the cache setting, Button 1 works while Button 2 does not.  And with the opposite cache setting, then Button 1 doesn't always work and Button 2 always does.  The problems are consistent across both Android and Apple devices.  I need a solution that allows them both to work 100% of the time....preferably with the `cache:false`.

## The code and descriptions:

`Button 1: hides/displays various page elements to hide/display the camera view with "scanner" box beneath the app.`

**with cache:false** = the below code works 100% of the time.

**with cache:true** = works about 50% of the time, though the camera scanning functionatity still works, the user doesn't see the camera view or scanner target causing them to think the button action did nothing.

```
  $scope.scannerOn = 0 ;  // initializes scanner tracker to off
  function scannerBox(x) {
    // gf.elm is a shorthand global function for `angular.element['#'+id]
    var appNavView = gf.elm("appNavView") ;  
    var allTabs = gf.elm("allTabs") ;  
    var tabClubs = gf.elm("tab-clubs")
    var divPane = appNavView.children[0] ;
    var ionViewSearch = gf.elm("ionViewClubDetail")
    var eventWrapper = gf.elm("eventWrapperC") ;
    var scannerDiv = gf.elm("scannerClubDiv") ;
    var scannerParentDiv = scannerDiv.parentNode ;
    if (x == 0) { // close
      allTabs.style.background = "white" ;
      tabClubs.style.background = "white" ;
      divPane.style.background = "white" ; //
      ionViewSearch.style.background = "white" ;
      eventWrapper.style.display = "" ;
      scannerDiv.style.display = "none" ;
      scannerParentDiv.style.height = "" ;
    } else if (x == 1) { //open
      allTabs.style.background = "none transparent" ;
      tabClubs.style.background = "none transparent" ;
      divPane.style.background = "none transparent" ; //
      ionViewSearch.style.background = "none transparent" ;
      eventWrapper.style.display = "none" ;
      scannerDiv.style.display = "" ;
      scannerParentDiv.style.height = "100%" ;    
    }
  }
```

`Button 2: loads tickets into a modal view with an in-app generated QR Code.`

**with cache:false** = QR Codes are loaded upon FIRST modal open, but if user closes the modal and opens again OR the tickets refresh (every 5 minutes), the QR Codes disappear and no new ones can be generated in place of the original.  The users sees a blank area with the QR Code should be.

**with cache:true** = QR Code appears everytime the user opens the modal.

```
  $scope.openTicketModal = function() {
    
    // this interval is need to let ng-repeat in modal populate
    // before triggering the genQRCode() function - otherwise, the genQRCode()
    // will create the code and try to attach the `canvas` to the DIV
    // before the div is actually rendered - causing it to fail.
    //
    // this is needed because modal template/scripts are loaded into memory
    // when page/controller is loaded (even before modal is opened) causing genQRCode()
    // to initialize cause the same DIV not yet created issue above.  Not certain how to get
    // ng-repeat to call function on $last element AFTER the modal is opened. bizarre behavior.
    if ($scope.club.tickets.length > 0) {
      var tik = $scope.club.tickets[$scope.club.tickets.length-1] ;
      var lastTicket = gf.ang("ticketID_"+tik.ticketID) ;
      $scope.ticketInit = $interval(function() {
        if (lastTicket) {
          $scope.genQRCode() ;
          $interval.cancel($scope.ticketInit) ;
        }
      },100) ;
      //$scope.tixModal.show() ;
      $rootScope.globalModalShow($scope.tixModal) ;
    } else {
      pt = "TICKETS" ;
      ps = "OOOOPPS" ;
      pm = "It seems no tickets were purchased for this event." ;
      ps1 = '' ;
      pm1 = "If you believe this to be an error, please contact your event host admin." ;
      pa = 0 ;
      $rootScope.globalPopover(pt,ps,pm,ps1,pm1,pa) ;
      return ;
    }
  } ;

  // tickets are refreshed every 5 minutes.
  // 
  $scope.ticketTimer ;
  $scope.ticketCSS = {} ;
  $scope.genQRCode = function() {
    $scope.refreshTickets = 1 ;
    clubService.getTickets($scope.club.cID,$scope.club.clID,$scope.club.ceID)
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.refreshTickets = 0 ;
      if (response.success == true) {
        for (var x=0;x<response.tickets.length;x++) {
          var ticket = response.tickets[x] ;
            $scope.ticketCSS[ticket.ticketID] = {} ;
          // clear existing <canvas> from ticketDIV otherwise
          // the jQuery qrcode will just add more qrCodes to the DIV
          gf.ang("ticketID_"+ticket.ticketID).empty() ;
          if (ticket.scode == 0) {
            var ts = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 5 * 60000).toISOString().slice(0,19).replace("T"," ") ;
            $scope.ticketCSS[ticket.ticketID].status = "Open" ;
            $scope.ticketCSS[ticket.ticketID].stampTitle = "Refresh" ;
            $scope.ticketCSS[ticket.ticketID].stampText = ts ;
            $scope.ticketCSS[ticket.ticketID].img = "img/LiveScanner.gif" ;
            $scope.ticketCSS[ticket.ticketID].stampColor = "black" ;
          } else if (ticket.scode == 1) {
            var tsTemp = ticket.sdate.replace(/-/g, "/") ;
            var ts = new Date(tsTemp).toISOString().slice(0,19).replace("T"," ") ;
            $scope.ticketCSS[ticket.ticketID].status = "Scanned" ;
            $scope.ticketCSS[ticket.ticketID].stampTitle = "Scanned" ;
            $scope.ticketCSS[ticket.ticketID].stampText = ts ;
            $scope.ticketCSS[ticket.ticketID].stampColor = "green" ;
            $scope.ticketCSS[ticket.ticketID].img = "img/scanned1.png" ;
          } else if (ticket.scode == 2) {
            var tsTemp = ticket.sdate.replace(/-/g, "/") ;
            var ts = new Date(tsTemp).toISOString().slice(0,19).replace("T"," ") ;
            $scope.ticketCSS[ticket.ticketID].status = "Expired" ;
            $scope.ticketCSS[ticket.ticketID].stampTitle = "Expired" ;
            $scope.ticketCSS[ticket.ticketID].stampText = ts ;
            $scope.ticketCSS[ticket.ticketID].img = "img/expired.png" ;
            $scope.ticketCSS[ticket.ticketID].stampColor = "red" ;
          }
          if (ticket.ticketRefund == 0) {
            var refund = "No" ;
          } else {
            var refund = "Yes" ;
          }
          $scope.ticketCSS[ticket.ticketID].refunds = refund ;
          $scope.ticketCSS[ticket.ticketID].trans = "No" ;
          $scope.ticketCSS[ticket.ticketID].desc = ticket.ticketDesc ;

          // dynamically create the QR Code
          jQuery('#ticketID_'+ticket.ticketID).qrcode({width:150,height:150,text:ticket.liveCode}) ;
        }
      }
    }) ;
```